# How to fill the surface of a "wireframe"-sphere in Blender

Tags: mesh, vertices, wireframe, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface

I have half a sphere together with a full sphere as separate objects in a blender file. I load them from a X3D file I generate externally. I get them as something, which seems to be something like a wire-frame to me (maybe different what Blender calls wire-frame-objects). Instead of this wire-frame I want a closed surface – one for the sphere and one for the half sphere.

[image]

The problem is that I am a total beginner in Blender. What I have tried so far is the following:

1) select one of the objects (let's say the full sphere, see first image)

2) <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> select *Mesh From Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*

3) select *Edit Mode*

4) <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

My hope was that Blender only fills the faces orthogonal to the normals of the sphere. Unfortunately it does not work like I hoped. Could someone help me a bit. I am a total beginner to blender and mostly do not know how to access the options, if someone could explain it for an absolute beginner, this would help me a lot.

I attached a blend-file:

[image]

Comment: add mofifier - cast - - - that seem to work in a new tutorial (2020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have curves. So when converted to mesh, they are disconnected rings or arcs but this is not visible as vertices overlap.

In edit mode:

- select all
- remove doubled vertices (you find that in the toolshelf on the left using <kbd>T</kbd> to make it appear, or press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the menu to select it from)
- then once all is selected hit <kbd>F</kbd>

I confirm this hypothesis after a test on your file.

[image]

Concerning the half sphere, same principle but you'll have to remove the unwanted face after that:

- Switch to face selection mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, then choose 'face'
- Select it <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Delete it <kbd>X</kbd> then 'only face'

[image]

Comment: This works very well for the full sphere. But in fact I must fill just the faces, because if I apply this trick to the half sphere also the volume is filled I think. Could you explain how to fix this, such that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

A whole sphere can't be filled by using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. Select some of the faces but make sure they aren't in a continuous loop(you shouldn't be able to go around the sphere on your selected faces). Repeat this as much as possible then fill in the leftovers manually using <kbd>F</kbd>.

Or just select each face one by one and press <kbd>F</kbd> each time.